# Imitating ViewState into WinForm's

Tags: c#, winforms, viewstate

If it's possible it would be a great thing.

So is there a way how to achieve somehow a **ViewState** behavior into a **WinForm's** Application.

Like if i have a Bunch of `TextBoxes` ,than uses types text into them ,`TextBoxes` should store Their Text ,Location ,Size etc. and on Next Application Startup they should Load their Content Text ,Location ,Size etc.

Further...every `Control` into every Form ,should store Their State somehow ,and on Load ,they should Load their Content and Other Properties like they where last time Application was running.

PS : If there is not any Library or already made Solution ,than please don't try to spend time writing Code ,because it's not Fear to ask you guy's for Code ,i need just Direction's and Ideas because i plan to achieve it by my-self.Down-Voter's please consider that!!!

Comment: This doesn't sound like ViewState emulation. In fact, ViewState is rather a way for web forms to emulate the state in winforms. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using my google-fu [I found this on code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/SavingTheStateOfAForm.aspx).

The guy's written some code that effectively serializes a form out to XML so you can load it back in again.  Don't know if it would cope with forms with dynamic controls that perhaps aren't on the form when you load it back in again - but I'm sure you can tweak the code to do what you want.

Comment: @Cody, since you accepted this answer, perhaps you can write a line or two about to what degree it solved your problem, and whether the issues mentioned in this answer were any problems.